# Pip install: Error "No module named 'setuptools' "

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyinstaller, setuptools

I've been having trouble installing pyinstaller on Windows. Using the command:

`C:\Users\Chris>py -m pip install pyinstaller --user`

I keep getting the error:

`Collecting pyinstaller Using cached PyInstaller-3.3.tar.gz Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools' ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Chris\Ap pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jvfkrm8f\pyinstaller\`

I have tried upgrading setuptools

`C:\Users\Chris>py -m pip install setuptools --upgrade Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\chris\lib\site-packages`

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling setuptools.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If it does not break your environment, you could try without the --user. And/or perhaps in a virtualenv.

Comment: Still failed without --user. How would I go about making a virtual environment?

Comment: venv is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), but I just suggested it for the case if you did not want to alter your main environment. So it would not solve anything about setuptools

Comment: If you just launch python, does an ```import setuptools``` run successfully?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error and there is no accompanying text output. Trying pip install after that still throws the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
pip<py version> install pyinstaller --user
```

Like

```
pip3.6 install pyinstaller
```

Comment: Same error `C:\Users\Chris>pip3.6 install pyinstaller --user`
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Chris\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dafcvasf\pyinstaller\`